# What is the best way to to instruct Django to run custom SQL after syncdb?

Tags: django

There are many times when I would like to apply some custom schema definitions (functions, views, types, triggers, ...)
when a new database is initialized or before tests run.  I conjured up the following addition to `settings.py`, which does work

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_syncdb
from django.db import connection

# Apply schema changes not defined by Django. Set a module-level
# flag to guard against multiple invocations of syncdb_handler()

def syncdb_handler(**kwargs):
    if getattr(connection, 'syncdb_called', None):
        return
    connection.syncdb_called = True
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(open('/path/to/schema.sql')).read())

post_syncdb.connect(syncdb_handler)
```

The documentation does not seem to suggest a solution like this. Is there a convention for applying custom SQL as part of database creation?

In this example the connect handler is called multiple times and keeping a global variable doesn't seem like a good design pattern.

Comment: did you manage to sort this out?

Comment: No, because we are using Django 1.4 and we have a large application that has proven to be very difficult to migrate to a later version.

Comment: oops! I guess you don't need me to tell you that 1.4 is now unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `post_syncdb` signal was he preferred way of doing things in the past (though it was most unusual to place this code in settings.py).

But syncdb is no longer being used. Now databases are created and modified with [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/). With that the practice is to use a `migrations.RunSQL` or `migrations.RunPython` make customized changes to the database if needed.